# Sending Email's using tomcat server through a PHP aplication

Tags: php, email, tomcat, email-client

I have deployed a PHP application on my tomcat server(Tomcat 6.0).Previously I was using XAMPP,but this needs specifically to be run on tomcat.I used [this](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php) java bridge for that.Now I am not able to send mail through this,**from localhost** using gmail SMTP.

In XAMPP I used the **sendmail.exe client** for sending mails through LOCALHOST,but i don't know how to do it using tomcat.Tried to search but found hardly anything!!Badly stuck!Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can the **mail.jar** in **tomcat lib** be used for this purpose??Or I read a few posts where thy said calling a apache service using tomcat is possible.But how to achieve it??No guidelines!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to send email from within your PHP application, then you want to us the built-in `mail` function ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You can configure how `mail` behaves with various options documented on http://www.php.net/.

From PHP, you aren't going to be able to use any services provided by Tomcat for SMTP.

Comment: Yes I am sending it within application and it works with XAMPP apache server,but t won't with tomcat.As php/java brdge for connection isn't there anything for email client.Like calling a apachec service using tomcat

Comment: Your PHP binary should include everything necessary to make an SMTP connection: I believe neither XAMPP nor Tomcat have anything to do with it.

Comment: I am aware of that.I have been using sendmail.exe and its libraries for sending mails using XAMPP,but tomcat as a java container would need something like sendmail client.Offcourse in Java applications we can use Mail.jar for achieving this,but how can I call the mail.jar classes using PHP?? that's my question.Sorry if asking for more,but i hope someone might have done it and I am really short of time.Thanks for your views

Comment: Accepted the answer as it helped me to go in the right direction and upvoted the comment that helped me to do so. Thanks @Christopher